# How can I replace the frame of ordinary numbers (e.g. 84 to 106) by another frame (e.g. 95 to 117)?

Tags: r, replace

I have tried `replace` function like

```
df$x<-replace(df$x,84:106, 95:117)
```

tried with `seq` and `c` and with different variations of `lapply` e.g.

```
df$x<-lapply(df$x, replace, 84:106, 95:117)
```

and again with `c` and `seq` but didn't get the desired result.

The (IMHO) simplest solution,

```
df$x[df$x==c(84:106)]<-c(95:117)
```

did not work either.

Comment: Can you please provide a small example of `df$x` and the expected result?

Comment: one of the most recent try:
patient_ab_sec1$Patient.ID[which(patient_ab_sec1$Patient.ID==c(84:106))]<-list(c(95:117))
Resulted in warning message: In patient_ab_sec1$Patient.ID == c(84:106) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
df$x <- ifelse(df$x >=84 & df$x <=106, x+11,x)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, guys. I have used these codes, they seem to work good, but in the near future, we will get new data and new discrepancies will occur.

Answer (score 1):

`replace` seems unnecessary here:

```
df$x = df$x + 11
```

Or, if you want to replace only numbers inside that range and no others:

```
in_range = df$x >= 84 & df$x <= 106
df$x[in_range] = df$x[in_range] + 11
```

Comment: it seems to be better to use `df$x[df$x %in% c(84:106)] +11`

Comment: Yes, it could work, but I have to replace only the specific "part" of the column and not all variables.

Comment: I can try for this specific part, but it is the temporary solution, isn't it? I am not sure that in future, numbers will differ exactly of 11.

Comment: @JakhongirAlidjanov That’s what my second piece of code does. It’s hard to understand exactly what yuor goal is.

Comment: But there are other tables, where these patient id-numbers differ as well, but values are other than the difference of 11. Therefore, I'd appreciate if one could propose the solution, which could be kinda 'universal'.

Answer (score 1):

Assumming you don't exactly want a `+11` operation, you can do:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(x = 1:5, y = 2:6)

dt[, x := replace(x, which(x %in% 2:5), 8:11)]
```

That way you can also do:

```
dt[, x := replace(x, which(x %in% 8:11), c(21, 24, 45, 65))]
```